# Not letting me import modules in Ember js for some reason or an another

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, axios

I have just started a small Ember project just to get my self familiar with it and it's causing me a headache at the moment because it just refuses to play ball with npm imports.

So i have a component that i am trying to import axios into and it just keeps saying `Could not find module npm:axios` and for the life of me i cant figure our why.

Here is my code

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import axios from 'npm:axios';

import emailValidate from '../validators/email';

export default Component.extend({
  isValidEmail: false,
  actions: {
    onChange: function(value) {
      this.set('isValidEmail', emailValidate(value));

      if (emailValidate(value)) {

        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users/').then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
  },

 }
});
```

I have also tried `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: Do you have [`ember-auto-import`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) as a dependency of your app? This adds support for importing arbitrary npm packages. It will be added to default blueprint soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to import from an npm package in an ember app, [The Octane Edition of Ember recommends](https://octane-guides-preview.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/#toc_regular-npm-packages) to use [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import).

To do this, at the root of your ember app, run:

```sh
ember install ember-auto-import
```

Then, after adding axios to your `package.json` via `npm install -D axios` or `yarn add -D axios`, you will be able to import it with

```js
import axios from 'axios';
// import axios from 'npm:axios'; this import is wrong
```

Comment: I would say: You should use ember-auto-import. There are several other ways to include npm packages. Especially used before ember-auto-import existed. But I wouldn't recommend any of them. One of them required to prefix the import with `npm:`.

Comment: @jelhan I've edited my answer to integrate your comment 

Answer (score -1):

Do you have entry of axios in package.json. you first have to install axios in your node_modules by: `npm install axios --save`. This will make entry into package.json
Then restart your server. This should fix your issue. 
P.S: Not sure why you have imported like 'npm:axios' instead 
import axios from 'axios';
I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: This doesn’t seem Ember-specific to me 

Comment: modern ember doesn't do anything ember specific with imports -- did you see the accepted answer?